# Building a mobile app using my current website

Tags: android, ios, iframe, web, responsive-design

- Is it possible with iframe-like ?
- I have a responsive website.
- My goal is to deploy my website as an application.
- App will be deployed for iOS and Android
- I don't want to use 3rd party provider whomever promises to convert my website into android app.

What is the easiest / fastest way to deploy an app using current website ? I thought of iframe-like but i know this community know better. I need your advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can go for cordova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the [Webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) class in android. This is the iframe like thing you are looking for.

Comment: is there anything possible like this, for iOS ?

Comment: Certainly this : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/

Comment: Thanks, you've been so helpful.